# Pytorch convolution input reshaping

Tags: cnn, pytorch

I am new to CNNs, and I'm trying to follow along with [a Pytorch DCGAN tutorial](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/dcgan_faces_tutorial.html#generative-adversarial-networks) by reimplementing it in Keras. Clearly there are some differences in the frameworks, but in particular I am struggling to understand how the input noise vector is handled per the following image of the generator architecture:

[image: Generator architecture]

The code goes on to define the first layer of the network as:

```
# input is Z, going into a convolution
nn.ConvTranspose2d( nz, ngf * 8, 4, 1, 0, bias=False),
nn.BatchNorm2d(ngf * 8),
nn.ReLU(True),
# state size. (ngf*8) x 4 x 4
```

Where nz = 100 (size of noise vector) and ngf = 64.

How does that work? Is the noise vector implicitly reshaped by that first convolutional layer to a (?, 4, 4) tensor, as suggested by the diagram? How would that even work? Is there an implicit dense connection between the noise vector and the convolutional layer? How does that first layer result in a tensor of shape (64*8, 4, 4) per the comment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out to be a dumb question in the end - the noise vector is simply treated as a 1x1 array with "depth" (i.e. number of channels/features) of 100, which can of course be processed by the ConvTranspose2d layer. This reshaping to 1x1x100 just has to be explicitly specified as the first layer in keras:

```
model.add(Reshape((1, 1, 100), input_shape=(100,)))
```